# How to use column values in Python user define function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I want to check values of a column inside a user defined function, if the column has value 1 it will return 1 and if the value is 0 it will return a 0. Then, I wanted to create a new column with these values

```py
def count_developer(x): 
    if ['datascientist'] == "1":
        return 1 
    else:
        return 0

dat2['count_developer'] = dat2.apply(count_developer,axis=1)
```

but, I am getting only "0" as value in the newly created column "count_developer", though the column "datascientist" has both 0 and 1 as value

Comment: Does `'datascientist'` only have `0`s and `1`s?

Comment: `['datascientist']` is a list containing a string.  It will never equal the string `"1"` which is why `0` is returned.  The last line can't be reached.  The parameter `x` is never used.  Did you mean `dat2['datascientist']`?  Is `dat2` a global variable?

Comment: Yes, 'datascientist' field only has 0 and 1

Comment: yes, `dat2` is a global variable

Answer (score 0):

Try with:
You are returning 0 and 1. So it will not executing next line.

```
def count_developer(x): 
    if ['datascientist'] == "1":
        return_val = 1 
    else:
        return_val = 0
    dat2['count_developer'] = dat2.apply(count_developer,axis=1)
    return return_val
```

Comment: It is still returning 0 only, the new column `count_developer` has only 0 values

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def count_developer(x): 
    if ['datascientist'] == 1 or ['datascientist'] == "1":
        return 1 
    else:
        return 0
dat2['count_developer'] = dat2.apply(count_developer,axis=1)
```

Comment: Tried, but it is still returning 0 only, the new column count_developer has only 0 values